# How to calculate the width, height or length (in pixels) of an object?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is there a function to calculate the horizontal or vertical length of an object that I obtained by applying bwboundaries?

Comment: Don't use `bwboundaries`.  Use `regionprops` instead.  Much easier. Refer to the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width/height by looking at the min and max values (range) of the X,Y coordinates in each individual boundary object. Another solution is to simply use the bwconncomp->regionprops-> BoundingBox